# Generic collection algorithms in C#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, generics

Is there a library of generic collection algorithms for .NET? I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
IList<T> items = GetItemsFromSomeWhere();
Algorithms<T>.Sort(items);
//
// ....
//
T item = GetItemSomwHow();
int i = Algorithms<T>.IndexOf(items, item);
```

Note, that `items` is not `List<T>`, otherwise I could simply use the `List<T>.Sort` and `List<T>.BinarySearch` methods.

Of course, I can implement them myself, I just do not want to reinvent the wheel.

I would also like the implementation to be efficient.

P.S.

Please, do not advise on which collections to use. I am perfectly aware of the `Array` or `List<T>` abilities. What I need is a library of algorithms to work on any `IList<T>` based collection.

**EDIT:**
Found what I needed - see my own answer.

Comment: Guys, you do not have anything else to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I have found the [PowerCollections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections) library from `Wintellect`.

Aside from supplying various collections it provides a static `Algorithms` class with quite a few algorithms, including `BinarySearch<T>` and `SortInPlace<T>`, which expect  **any** `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

[`System.Linq.Enumerable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_members.aspx) does a bunch of good stuff. Admittedly, it does miss some stuff but it's applicable nevertheless.

Comment: No; it doesn't do binary searches

Comment: Well, binary search is only applicable on lists with O(1) index-based access time. `Array.BinarySearch` will do it for arrays.

Comment: Guys, I have IList<T>, not List<T> or T[]. I need a solution for any IList<T> based collection. So, how Array.BinarySearch is helping me?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, .NET doesn't provide built in BinarySearch implementations that work with the `IList<T>` interface.

You can use Linq for sorting your generic list, as other posters have mentioned. But for binary search on `IList<T>`, I would suggest you [check out the following SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967047/how-to-perform-a-binary-search-on-ilistt).

I am not aware of a good, general purpose algorithms library that you can use to fill in the gaps in Linq, although I suspect that a lot of people out there have implemented their own utilities to solve similar problems.

Comment: Check out my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library as a template: [Generic Sorting Library](https://github.com/akshaykamath/SortingLibrary)

It is still a work in progress and does not contain all the sorting algorithms. However, you can use it as a template and build on it.

It exposes a sort() as an extension method over IList and requires you to specify the sorting algorithm and a comparer. so your code could be written as follows:

```
int[] sortingArray = { 12, 5, 2, 7, 66 };
IComparer<int> comparer = new SortComparer();
sortingArray.Sort(SortStrategy.HeapSort, comparer);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array_methods%28VS.71%29.aspx) class might work for you ([Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort(VS.71).aspx) and [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310886(VS.71).aspx)).

Could do the following:

```
IList<string> foo = new List<string>();
foo.Add("hi");
foo.Add("bye");
string[] foo_temp = new string[foo.Count];
foo.CopyTo(foo_temp, 0);
Array.Sort<String>(foo_temp);
foo = new List<string>(foo_temp);
```

Comment: I think the asker is looking for a set algorithms that work a generic collection, not asking for advice on which collection to use.

Comment: No; it only works on arrays.  He wants to call things on any `IList<T>`

Answer (score 0):

You just gave the definition for LINQ with the OrderBy extension method.

Comment: No; he wants to sort in-place

Comment: I think sort is just an example - LINQ has a lot of collection-manipulation functions but I suspect he's interested in other stuff. I've seen Set<T> implementations that do intersection, union, etc. but not sure if that's what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

[IndexOfKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.indexofkey.aspx) method of SortedList<> does a BinarySearch internally.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what data structures you are using and what algorithms are actually possible on it.  I know you don't want to read about collections, but obviously binary search doesn't work on a linked list.  What kind of algorithms do you need?  The efficient sorting algorithms are there already.  Linq and the .NET collections should give you everything you need.

Comment: No, he specifically wants IList algorithms, and the two examples he gives could be implemented for IList in the BCL, but currently aren't. They are tied to List and Array.

Answer (score 0):

I also hit this problem. My solution was to use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to find out the implementations of `List.Sort` and `Array.BinarySearch` and rewrite them as extension methods for `IList<T>`.

Even if you don't write them as extensions but as ordinary static methods (e.g. if you're using C# 2), you don't need your exact syntax:

```
Algorithms<T>.Sort(items);
```

Just make `Sort` a static generic method, in an ordinary static (non-generic) class `Algorithms`, and type inference will do the rest by looking at the type of the argument:

```
Algorithms.Sort(items);
```

Comment: Check out my own answer.