# Can I use BinarySearch over a List of (start, end) Ranges to find a number covered by one Range

Tags: c#, list, binary-search

I have a list of ranges, for example: (0, 1), (1, 4), (4, 8), (8, 14), (14, 20),

where Range is class with Start & End.

Can I apply a BinarySearch for searching a segment which contains value 10?

Any other way to implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by "contains value 10" ? Does range 8-14 contain 10 ?

Comment: Are the ranges always sequential, or can they overlap?

Comment: Range are always sequential. Yes, range 8-14 contains 10.

Comment: What if instead of 10, we search for the number 4 ? Which range contains it (1-4), (4-8) or none ?

Comment: @digEmAll Let's put that Range contains value only when: start <= value < End

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# binarysearch a list<T> by a member of T](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565844/c-sharp-binarysearch-a-listt-by-a-member-of-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrote my own function:

```
public Range BinarySearch(double position)
{
    Range part = null;

    int from = 0;
    int to = Count - 1;
    while (from < to)
    {
        int middle = (from + to) / 2;
        part = this[middle];

        switch (part.CompareTo(position))
        {
            case 1:
                from = Math.Min(middle + 1, to);
                break;
            case -1:
                to = Math.Max(middle - 1, from);
                break;
            case 0:
                from = to = middle;
                break;
        }
    }

    return this[to];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to compare a Range object to double? In any case beware of the overflow in the line `middle = (from + to) / 2`.

Answer (score 2):

The general and most efficient way to query a collection of ranges, is implementing an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). However, since your intervals never overlap, you can use a [binary search approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Naive_approach).

So, here's what I would do.

Considering the `Range` class implemented as follows:

```
class Range
{
    public int Start { get; private set; }
    public int End { get; private set; }
    public Range(int start, int end)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }
}
```

We create a comparer for the `Range` class that considers only the `Start` property (it's sufficient, since we assume there's no overlap) :

```
class StartOnlyRangeComparer : IComparer<Range>
{
    public int Compare(Range x, Range y)
    {
        return x.Start.CompareTo(y.Start);
    }
}
```

Then, here are the most important methods wrapped in an extensions class:

```
static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// N.B. ranges must be sorted by ascending Start, must contain 
    ///      non overlapping ranges and ranges with Start=End are not allowed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ranges"></param>
    /// <param name="point"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Range FindRangeContainingPoint(
        this IList<Range> ranges, int point)
    {
        if (ranges.Count == 0)
            return null;

        var index = ranges.FindFirstIndexGreaterThanOrEqualTo(
                    new Range(point, point + 1),
                    new StartOnlyRangeComparer());
        if (index < 0)
            return null; // no existing range contains the point, 
                         // if we wanted to insert a Range(point, point+1) 
                         // would be before the first element 
        if (index >= ranges.Count)
        {
            var lastElement = ranges[ranges.Count - 1];
            if (lastElement.ContainsPoint(point))
                return lastElement;
            else
                return null; // no existing range contains the point,  
                             // if we wanted to insert a Range(point, point+1)
                             // would be after the last element
        }
        if (ranges[index].ContainsPoint(point))
            return ranges[index];
        else if (index > 0 && ranges[index - 1].ContainsPoint(point))
            return ranges[index - 1];
        else
            return null; // no existing range contains the point,  
                         // if we wanted to insert a Range(point, point+1)
                         // would be at index - 1
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Lower Bound function on sorted list (see credits)
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="sortedCollection"></param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="comparer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int FindFirstIndexGreaterThanOrEqualTo<T>(
        this IList<T> sortedCollection,
        T key,
        IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        int begin = 0;
        int end = sortedCollection.Count;
        while (end > begin)
        {
            int index = begin + ((end - begin) / 2);
            T el = sortedCollection[index];
            if (comparer.Compare(el, key) >= 0)
                end = index;
            else
                begin = index + 1;
        }
        return end;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if point is included in [Start, End)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="point"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool ContainsPoint(this Range range, int point)
    {
        return range.Start <= point && range.End > point;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Range>()
        {
            new Range(0, 1), 
            new Range(1, 4), 
            new Range(4, 8), 
            new Range(8, 14), 
            new Range(14, 20),
            new Range(22, 24),
        };

        // yes I know in this case they're already sorted...
        // but I want to stress the fact that you must sort the list
        list.Sort(new StartOnlyRangeComparer()); 

        var range10 = list.FindRangeContainingPoint(10); // returns (8,14)
        var range21 = list.FindRangeContainingPoint(21); // returns null
        var range20 = list.FindRangeContainingPoint(20); // returns null
        var range14 = list.FindRangeContainingPoint(14); // return (14,20)
   }
}
```

Note that `Start` edge is included while `End` edge is excluded (e.g. see the `range20` example).

Credits to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594518/is-there-a-lower-bound-function-in-c-sharp-on-a-sortedlist) for the `FindFirstIndexGreaterThanOrEqualTo` method

Comment: Thanks for hint: Interval Tree

Answer (score 1):

You can use IComparer interface with [BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Regards

Comment: Thanks, seems it is a solution

Comment: No, BinarySearch require Range item for search. But I have value only, not range.

Comment: And I dont want to create dummy Range for search