# What is the fastest way to get all the keys between 2 keys in a SortedList?

Tags: c#, .net

Given a populated `SortedList<DateTime, double>`. I would like to get all the *keys* (or their index range, what should be a closed int interval (missed I something?)) for a given low and high DateTime interval.

Note: The low and high values are not necessary are actually in the SortedList.

---

If anyone has better idea how to do this without a SortedList, here is a bit wider scope what I would like to do, and I found SortedList may be suitable:

- I would like to cache doubles with a DateTime key.
- Access performance to the double having the given key is preferable over the performance of adding keys an removing keys
- Here is the thing: I must "invalidate" the cache for a given key range (delete the keys) Again there is no guarantee that the range min and max is exactly found in the cache.

Comment: So your question is basically get a range of keys?

Comment: Are you wedded to using `SortedList<DateTime, double>`? Could you perhaps use a `SortedSet<Tuple<DateTime, double>>` and a comparer that compares by `DateTime`? Then you could use `GetViewBetween`.

Comment: @Skeet SortedSet<Tuple<DateTime, double> is not a problem, just I was hoped that simple task can be accomplished with a "Sorted" thing like SortedList. I am afraid I was missing something about SortedList (never used)

Comment: You could also binary search the `Keys` such that the "lower" value is passed back to you on a search miss. `Keys` supports efficient indexed access and does not require copying to materialize, so everything should go quite nicely.

Comment: Related: [Binary Search on Keys of SortedList<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101820/binary-search-on-keys-of-sortedlistk-v)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wondered why `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` doesn't provide a `BinarySearch` when it's already sorted by the keys. It also uses the method itself(f.e. in `IndexOf`), but the array used is a private field. So i've tried to create an extension method for this. Have a look:

```
public static class SortedListExtensions
{
    public static int BinarySearch<TKey, TValue>(this SortedList<TKey, TValue> sortedList, TKey keyToFind, IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        TKey[] keyArray = sortedList.GetKeyArray();
        if (comparer == null) comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
        int index = Array.BinarySearch<TKey>(keyArray, keyToFind, comparer);
        return index;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TKey> GetKeyRangeBetween<TKey, TValue>(this SortedList<TKey, TValue> sortedList, TKey low, TKey high, IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        int lowIndex = sortedList.BinarySearch(low, comparer);
        if (lowIndex < 0)
        {
            // list doesn't contain the key, find nearest behind
            // If not found, BinarySearch returns the complement of the index
            lowIndex = ~lowIndex;
        }

        int highIndex = sortedList.BinarySearch(high, comparer);
        if (highIndex < 0)
        {
            // list doesn't contain the key, find nearest before
            // If not found, BinarySearch returns the complement of the index
            highIndex = ~highIndex - 1;
        }

        IList<TKey> keys = sortedList.Keys;
        for (int i = lowIndex; i < highIndex; i++)
        {
            yield return keys[i];
        }
    }
    
    private static TKey[] GetKeyArray<TKey, TValue>(this SortedList<TKey, TValue> sortedList)
    {
        // trying to resolve array with reflection because SortedList.keys is a private array
        Type type = typeof(SortedList<TKey, TValue>);
        FieldInfo keyField = type.GetField("keys", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if(keyField != null && keyField.GetValue(sortedList) is TKey[] keyArrayFromReflection)
        {
            return keyArrayFromReflection;      
        }
        
        // fallback: fill a new array from the public Keys property, you might want to log this since you should change the reflection implementation
        IList<TKey> keyList = sortedList.Keys;
        TKey[] keyArray = new TKey[keyList.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < keyArray.Length; i++)
            keyArray[i] = keyList[i];
        return keyArray;
    }
}
```

Create a sample `SortedList`:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-50);
var sortedList = new SortedList<DateTime, string>();
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i+=2)
{
    var dt = start.AddDays(i);
    sortedList.Add(dt, string.Format("Date #{0}: {1}", i, dt.ToShortDateString()));
}

DateTime low = start.AddDays(1);   // is not in the SortedList which contains only every second day
DateTime high = start.AddDays(10);
```

Now you can use the extension method to get the range of keys between a low- and high-key:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dateRange = sortedList.GetKeyRangeBetween(low, high).ToList();
```

Result:

```
04/04/2014
04/06/2014
04/08/2014
04/10/2014
```

Note that this is built from scratch and not really tested.

Comment: Hi @Tim, the moment you added the for loop to copy the contents to new array, it became O(n) instead of O(log n) for binary search. Is there any way to avoid this copy?

Comment: @Kiran: better late answer than never. Changed the extension little bit to try to resolve the `TKey[]` with reflection and fill that new array only as fallback.

Answer (score 3):

As the list is sorted you can use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to locate the endpoints of your interval. Worst case performance will be O(log n).

Comment: The endpoints are not necessary in the list. It will not work.

Comment: The worst case would be that all the keys in the list are equal, which would degenerate to O(n) unless the binary search is very carefully optimized to find the ends of the range in logarithmic time.

Comment: `SortedList.Keys` is an `IList<DateTime>` which is neither a `List<DateTime>` nor an `DateTime[]`, so how do you use `BinarySearch`?

Comment: @g.pickardou: It can certainly be made to work -- when binary search misses, it has effectively found the position where the search target would be *if it existed*. Consider than in C++, [`equal_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal_range/), which does exactly what you want, is logarithmic.

Comment: @TimSchmelter We can implement our own `BinarySearch` or a hack: use reflection to read the private array field.

Comment: Yes, I understand now: _I_ have to implement the bin search.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I dont see your issue.

Comment: @JonasJämtberg: the issue is that you cannot use `BinarySearch` on a `SortedList<DateTime, double>` because it doesn't support it. It uses it itself(for example in `IndexOf`), but the array used is private as Siriam has mentioned. Reflection is not an option.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm talking about implementing a binary search for the purpose.

Comment: btw do not take this as a complaining, but I can not believe I have to implement a binary search in _2014_ over a sorted thing just to get an item what is <= or >=

Comment: @g.pickardou I'm sure you can find a library with somewhere that will do it for you. However, implementing the algorithm is so simple that it is probably the quickest option.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem by running an adapted binary search on the `Keys` twice to find the indexes that bound the range of interest in the `Keys` collection.

Since `IList<T>` does not offer binary search facilities you need to write your own. Fortunately, there is also the option of stealing the ready-made implementation from [How to perform a binary search on IList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/967047/50079).

Here's an adapted version to find the lower bound:

```
public static int LowerBound<T>(this IList<T> list, T value, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (list == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

    comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;

    int lower = 0, upper = list.Count - 1;

    while (lower <= upper)
    {
        int middle = lower + (upper - lower) / 2;
        int comparisonResult = comparer.Compare(value, list[middle]);

        // slightly adapted here
        if (comparisonResult <= 0)
            upper = middle - 1;
        else
            lower = middle + 1;
    }

    return lower;
}
```

To implement `UpperBound`, simply change

```
if (comparisonResult <= 0)
```

to

```
if (comparisonResult < 0)
```

It's now trivial to do this:

```
var low = set.Keys.LowerBound(value);
var high = set.Keys.UpperBound(value);

// These extra comparisons are required because the adapted binary search
// does not tell us if it actually found the needle. They could be rolled
// into the methods themselves, but this would require another out parameter.
if (set.Keys[low] != value) ++low;
if (set.Keys[high] != value) --high;

if (low <= high) /* remove keys in the range [low, high] */
```