# C# LINQ - Find object in list between two properties

Tags: c#, linq

I haven't worked with LINQ before, but I know how efficient it is.
I have created a List with an object which you can see below:

```
public sealed class Item
{
    public long Start { private set; get; }
    public long End { private set; get; }
    public Item(string start, string end)
    {
        this.Start = Convert.ToInt64(start);
        this.End = Convert.ToInt64(end);
    }
}
```

This will be populated with `DataSet`s containing round about 200k Items.
Now, I want to select the best single item between the properties 'Start' and 'End'.

```
this.ItemList.Add(new Item(100000, 100002));
this.ItemList.Add(new Item(100003, 100006));
this.ItemList.Add(new Item(100007, 100012));
this.ItemList.Add(new Item(100013, 100026));
this.ItemList.Add(new Item(100027, 100065));
```

From another tool, I've got the value: `100009`

How can I get the object `new Item(100007, 100012)` back with LINQ? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What if given value fits two items as difference to both is equal? In particular what happens when the provided value is exactly between the end of one and the start of the next interval?

Comment: It's not clear what your criteria is - do you want to find all objects where start and end are both between two arbitrary values?

Comment: Define best. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a simple `Where` query should suffice:

```
long value = 100009;
var found = ItemList.Where(item => item.Start <= value && item.End >= value);
```

This will yield an `IEnumerable<Item>` containing all matching items. You can use `.First()`/`.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first matching item or continue to filter the result until you get the one you want.

Note that, if you really have 200k entries, a List might not be the most efficient data structure to search in (you have O(n) complexity). If performance is an issue, you might want to consider [using a `SortedList` and a binary search algorithm instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/967047/87698).

Comment: seems `First` rather: _i want to select the best one_

Comment: @Grundy: That depends on his definition of "best": first? smallest interval? closest to one of the boundaries?

Comment: yep, but _one_ i think say about select just one

Comment: @Grundy: I've modified my answer and mentioned `First` as an option.

Comment: I'd use FirstOrDefault instead, because it avoids null reference exception

Comment: @MVCDS Actually it avoids InvalidOperationException.

Comment: @MVCDS: It's the other way around: First will throw an `InvalidOperationException`, FirstOrDefault will yield null (which might later lead to a null reference exception, if you're not careful).